# The meaning of gemachter Mann

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is there such an expression in German: **gemachter Mann**? Is there any other meaning to it but *well-off man*?
How is it used?

Comment: We need the context.

Answer (score 4):

Ein gemachter Mann ist wohlhabend oder angesehen, am ehesten beides.

Usage:

> Mit diesem Vertrag in der Tasche war ich ein gemachter Mann.

Answer (score 1):

Laut dict.cc bedeudet, „ein gemachter Mann sein“, „to have got it made“ (als Idiom). „Er ist ein gemachter Mann heißt „He`s got it made.“ Man könnte auch sagen, „er ist ein wohlhabender Mann“, d.h, der hat Geld wie Heu.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it means *successful, prospered*.

We say:

- *Sie haben sich gemacht*, "You improved, you made something of yourself"
- *sich heraus machen*, like *herausputzen*, "to dress fancy", cp. "make-up"
- dialectal *to go somewhere*, e.g. *nach drüben machen*, "to go over there" (chiefly from the GDR to the BRD), *mach dich vom Acker*, "take a hike", perhaps cp. *to have come a long way*

> etc. etc.

A cross polination from *mögen* might be possible, i.e. *ein gemochter Mann*, "a well liked person", just like any other non-obvious derivation.

Compare *ein gestandener Mann*, "a well aged mann", *seinen Mann stehen* "to prove oneself", *ein angesehener Mann*, "a well regarded man", and perhaps *Stand*, "standing", *Ständegesellschaft* "rank-society", *Ansehen*, "respect".